# Documentation rollback not working: topic was a source of an example but is currently deleted

Tags: bug, documentation, rollbacks

I wanted to suggest a rollback of a change to one of my [documentation examples](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/121/concurrent-programming-threads/625/producer-consumer#t=201702070548289977022), when I encountered this error.

> Couldn't create rollback draft, topic "Thread Pools" (Id = 6061) was a
>   source of an example but is currently deleted.

Is it a SO error, or is there another reason I can't rollback the change?

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Could you add a link to the example and the version you want to roll back to?

Comment: I think someone deleted the example before you submitted the rollback.

Comment: @JonEricson link added.